# ¿Los archivos de .htaccess funcionan en las VM de Google Cloud?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, google-cloud-platform

Tengo un proyecto en una instancia de Compute Engine (GCP) el cual lo desarrolle en PHP, HTML, CSS, JS y de persistencia MySQL. El problema es el siguiente:

Al probar el proyecto en un servidor local (XAMP) funciona correctamente pero al migrar todo a la VM de Google carga la pagina inicial en [game.bochica.tk](http://game.bochica.tk) pero luego cuando ingresas los datos me aparece la siguiente imagen:

[image: error luego del acceso]

Luego de revisar todo el código deduje que el problema esta en que utilizo una variable llamada **Validar** para el redireccionamiento en mi index.php

Inicialmente tengo .htaccess en donde le doy valor a esa variable:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ index.php?validar=$1 [L]
```

y en mi index.php tengo esto:

```
if (isset($_GET["validar"])) {
 switch ($_GET["validar"]) {
  case "inicio":
   include "modules/inicio.php";
   break;
  case "salir":
   include "modules/salir.php";
   break;
  case "ingresoSF":
   include "modules/ingresoSF.php";
   break;
  default:
   include "views/modules/inicio.php";
   break;
 }
}else{
 include "modules/ingreso.php";
}
```

Alguien sabe si en las instancias de GCP funciona los .htaccess?

Comment: Revisá tener la directiva `AllowOverride All` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: Pues modifique el archivo /etc/apache2/apache2.conf y en el "Directory" coloque AllowOverride All, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error. Claro que yo tengo configurado mi servidor con 3 virtual host, no se si esa directiva debe ir en los archivos de lo virtual host.

Comment: En general los archivos `.htaccess` deberían no usarse, tal y como aconseja la documentación oficial https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/es/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que utilice archivos de configuración por directorio (`.htaccess`), se debe configurar la directiva [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) en el `.conf` de Apache:

```py
<Directory "/var/www">
    # permite modificar (override) cualquier config en ese directorio y subdirectorios
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```